# How is this "question" not spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

I came across [this "question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286905/cloudera-enterprise-5-8-is-released) in review:

[image]

At first I thought this was just yet another review audit because the question is so obviously spam. So I proceeded to flag it as such. Turns out it wasn't an audit.

However the question wasn't deleted as spam. Instead it was put on hold by a moderator as "unclear what you're asking". My spam flag was declined as "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer". (EDIT: my spam flag has changed from "declined" to "disputed")

Which leaves me scratching my head:

If this doesn't count as spam I honestly don't know what could possibly be considered spam? It's clearly advertising a product and nothing else.

Comment: I agree, this is spam - advertising a product in this way is very clearly spam

Comment: That's pretty clearly spam, and should've been flagged as such.

Comment: Another broken audit to add to the list :] ...

Comment: Hmm, it was just a spam question not caught nor by SO, nor by SmokeDetector, just flag it spam, when moderator comes by they will validate your flag (the people that closed it did wrong, but better closed then nothing, since at least the roomba would have got it). Did you have a decline flag?, Did you have problem in the review? You can also pass a comment on it to help other users like "Should not this be flagged as spam?"

Comment: @PetterFriberg: 2 mods are involved there, already. 1 closed it as unclear, another one deleted it.

Comment: So where is the problem?, if moderators did not like to punish user with -100 rep, ok, what problem did OP have?, declined flag?

Comment: Just to clarify: this wasn't an audit. It was a real question. I flagged it as spam. Moderator closed question as "unclear what you're asking". My spam flag was declined as "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"

Comment: @SvenSchoenung ok that's the issue, please consider to [edit] this in to your post.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Done.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327636/educating-people-to-flag-spam-and-not-vote-to-close

Comment: @SvenSchoenung: How long ago did you flag the question?

Comment: @Cerbrus 1 hour ago (2016-09-02 07:50:54Z)

Comment: Slight correction - your flag was **disputed** not declined. There's a difference. "Declined" means "no, you were wrong", "disputed" (in this context) means "your flag has merit, but it's not spam".

Comment: @ChrisF The flag was declined at first, then changed to disputed after I made the post here.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung - we can't (or at least I don't think we can) change the resolution of a flag that's already been processed. According to the flag history that I can see, it was always marked as "disputed".

Comment: @ChrisF I could have sworn the flag was declined at first, but I might have misread that.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung my apologies. Apparently if a mod disputes subsequent flags, the resolution of previous flags **is** changed.

Comment: I like to call these types of posts "indistinguishable from spam". On the surface, the post resembles spam through and through, but you had to take a second look, and suddenly there's that nagging little hint of "maybe, just maybe a really really really misguided little sap." I've come across a [couple](http://i.stack.imgur.com/26X2F.png) of these [cases](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ajpLc.png) myself, and never really known what to do with them beyond the obvious closing as unclear. (Although being a mod, I can always delete with a single click and be on my way.)

Comment: ^ In the latter case above, [I even told SOCVR that I wouldn't blame anyone for flagging that post as spam](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=31409265#31409265).

Answer (score -111, accepted):

I can't say for sure but *some reasons* behind not considering the post as spam might be:

- User has *other decent questions and answers*.
- User account has been there since 4 years.
- User has never been warned for spamming SO.

That might have made some mods think that it was not "exactly spam" but a "mistake". I agree with the mods here. This is not one of those "skin care" or "movers and packers" post. This could have been a mistake. **We don't want to block innocent people who unknowingly make some mistakes** (yes, we are assuming that). Hence those flags were **disputed** (not **declined**, which means—*you are clearly wrong*).

Comment: Sounds fair. However, shouldn't the question just have been deleted, then? Also, can you mark spam flags as helpful, without marking the Q/A as spam, or are those linked?

Comment: Maybe the account got hacked?

Comment: @S.L.Barth - May be. But I seriously doubt if that was indeed the case. Then again, we will have to give the OP the benefit of doubt.

Comment: @Cerbrus - *The mod might have thought that the roomba would have done that later?*

Comment: @TheLostMind: Good point. It would have, indeed.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Yes, they can be marked as *helpful* without making the Q & A as Spam.

Comment: In hindsight, from the user's perspective, that may have been better.

Comment: Hm yes. The user does seem to be active in the cloudera tag. The post also says "share the following news letter from Cloudera", and I don't think Cloudera needs spamvertizing. So they may indeed be acting in good faith. Still, using a question on SO to "share news" shows a misunderstanding of the purpose of SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus - IMO *disputed* flag means - *you are probably right. But we are not certain about it*

Comment: Hmm, according to me it is confusing, that mods choose to not spam nuke the post (since user has previous activity etc) **ok**, but if you are less then 10K a normal user can not see if a lot of deleted posts etc.. The post in itself is spam, so the best solution would have been to delete the post and mark the spam flag "approved". This with the spirit **normal** users moderates **posts**, **moderators** moderate **users**.

Comment: Ooooh. I always read it as _"This flag is incorrect, but there is indeed something wrong with the post."_ (so, not declined, but not right). My bad.

Comment: @S.L.Barth - Agreed. That question should not have been posted in the first place and that's where Qbans come in (IP block would have been an overkill) :P

Comment: @PetterFriberg - You are probably right. But the issue is- *with the data that you have, you can see that this is spam.. But with the data that we have, we have a good reason to believe that it isn't*. Yes, I would have probably deleted that post (which is its current state), but some mods prefer closing it and let the Roomba take care of it. In fact, in some cases, I let the the community cast delete votes on poor posts (even if I've seen it) even when one DV from me would nuke it. PS : You know I am always there in SOCVR :P

Comment: I can see the reasoning in your answer, but what would you advise I should do in the future? Just flag as spam again? Investigate the user and make a judgment call between spam flag and close vote (with all the possible downsides mentioned [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327636/educating-people-to-flag-spam-and-not-vote-to-close))?

Comment: @SvenSchoenung - Unfortunately when it comes to flagging posts as Spam, *the user's account has to be checked* (we've had spam flags cast on posts where the OP has 50K+ rep). Just looking at the post cannot help us in determining if that user is actually spamming or it was just a mistake. I suggest looking at the account (but if you are in a hurry, you can flag it as spam). Please ensure that it actually looks like spam (and is not VLQ / NAA). Or if you see an answer and are not sure if it is spam, flag it as NAA / VLQ. We will look into it :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Alright, I'll keep that in mind. Matter resolved as far as I'm concerned :)

Comment: What kind of "mistake" causes a user to post obvious spam under their user account? This just seems like *ex post facto* justification for a poor flag-handling decision to me. It doesn't matter if the user has ever spammed before, it matters that they are spamming *now*. For all you know, their account has been compromised. Remember that old mantra, act based on the *content*, not on the *user*? That applies here.

Comment: @CodyGray - What if the user didn't know that he wasn't supposed to post such posts on SO?. Ignorance deserves a penalty (Qban) but not something that's too harsh (IP block)

Comment: The part I'm not getting is how a user could possibly think that posting spam could be acceptable on *any* website, much less Stack Overflow. This isn't even a question, it's just a product announcement. There are no product announcements anywhere else on the site. You are suggesting to "please ensure that it actually looks like spam", but it clearly does. This couldn't be more spammy if it came out of a can. As for what the proper penalty is, that isn't the flagger's problem. Nor should it be yours. If something is obviously spam, you mark it as spam. End of discussion.

Comment: "User has other decent questions and answers." Do they? [Their questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1494045/ramesha-ks?tab=questions) range from `-6` to `0` and most are sitting with at least one close vote.

Comment: No @Cody, [that was discussed before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326027/procedure-to-handle-spammy-product-recommendations-posted-in-good-faith). Before throwing red flags on people that have other posts (and not spam posts), the first step is to educate and then to warn moderators. You know, leaving a helpful and constructive comment. It could be that it was intended all along, we don't know but you should never assume malice.

Comment: I don't think it was spam, I think it's a clueless OP.

Comment: @CodyGray - Why would a user wait 4 years to create a post like this unless he didn't know that it was wrong?. Most spam accounts are created and used on the same day. The account pattern doesn't match a usual spam account's pattern. Why is it so difficult to at least try to think that it could have been a legit case where the OP misunderstood what SO was for? Also, as I've already mentioned earlier, acting based on post and not on user doesn't work in case of spam / rude flags. We have to investigate the account. If we see a spam post from your account, we won't block you immediately

Comment: OK, don't spam-nuke a post, assuming good will. But why not manually delete the post while you're at it? The *post* is spam, and is clearly of no value as such.

Comment: So we are supposed to vote on questions not users, but mods can decide obvious spam might be OK based on a user not a question?

Comment: @AndrasDeak - Agreed. The post should probably have been nuked. It was of hardly any value (and a mod did that actually)

Comment: @TheLostMind well as it stands, the mod cast the third delete vote...so it would've gone anyway, with help from any other high-rep user. Waste of delete votes from 2 users before that...

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - When it comes to spam, a lot of people that I know look at the user's account if they are not certain that it is spam. I am not saying that it should be done but as mods, we usually do our research and check account (because we've had cases of crap being posted from accounts that were hacked)

Comment: The process of using flags on this site has become an exercise in doublethink. We already have semi-weekly semantic arguments about the meaning of the term "answer", and now we are judging a _copy-paste of a marketing mailing_ based on whether the user who posted it seems, on balance, to probably be an okay fellow? This is absurd.

Comment: Please keep in mind, we're discussing a post that is closed - by a moderator in response to a flag - and deleted - by a moderator in response to a flag. In terms of the world-visible outcome, there isn't a problem; we're bickering over statuses visible only to mods and flaggers on a weird edge-case. Perhaps the solution here is to stop displaying flag statuses, and let folks surmise the results based on what actions were / were not taken... As we had to do with flag weight a few years back for pretty much the same reasons.

Comment: @Shog9 what do you mean by "deleted by a moderator in response to a flag"? Did somebody re-flag the post after the declined spam flags?

Comment: Yes, lots @Andras.

Comment: So, what's the point of a -100 rep penalty on a flag that should only be used for users that haven't had the chance to get 100 rep?

Comment: *"Why would a user wait 4 years to create a post like this unless he didn't know that it was wrong?"* Well, exactly. When I first read that, I thought you were agreeing with me. Then I realized that there is an alternate interpretation and that is probably the one you meant. But follow my logic: if a user really thought this kind of thing was acceptable, why did they wait 4 years until they started doing it? Why didn't they post "product announcements" when they first joined? And the rest of this is just why you should [feature-request] a spam deletion button that doesn't penalize the user.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: Nobody actually knows. Last I heard some of the mods too were questioning the purpose of having a rep penalty.

Comment: @Shog9: Cue all the repeated flags and/or meta posts raised because "my flag doesn't seem to have been acted upon"

Comment: If there's an apple in the cereal aisle, is it Cinnamon Toast Crunch? No. The post in question is 100% pure spam, and no amount of rep or veteran status should excuse that. Besides, the user who posted that has five questions and five answers, not a single one of which is positive, so I don't even see how they would qualify for special treatment.

Comment: If the complaints were, "I think this flag should have been handled differently", that's useful, @boltclock. "The outcome is fine but I want a bigger number" is less often so productive.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the author is blocked for repeated crap questions anyway, @thelostmind.

Comment: @Shog9 - Yes, I already mentioned that (gave a subtle hint about the OP's account being QBanned) :)

Comment: @shog9 It's not just about a magic number. Apparently you are now explicitly alerting people when one of their recent flags has been declined. I had a flag declined the other day (which I didn't know about because I never check my flagging history), but got a message about it the next time I tried to flag something. Well, that pissed me off. The message implied I didn't know what I was doing when flagging, so I checked up on it, confirmed that I *did* in fact know what I was doing, and re-flagged with a custom message. Part of the problem is senseless flag handling on obvious crap answers...

Comment: And as I said to Bolt, this sort of criticism is valuable @Cody. Not so much the endless discussion of flag statuses. When reviewers handle flags, they don't get to pick a status; they just pick an action. I suspect allowing mods to do the same might be a useful change for everyone involved.

Comment: @TheLostMind, be less subtle. Right now your answer implies the choice of resolution was useful in maintaining a good standing for the author, which... Is probably unwarranted, and certainly non-existent.

Comment: @Shog9: Nah, the complaints are "Is anyone home??? Why has no one handled my flag?"

Comment: Why does this have a delete vote? -.-

Comment: @CodyGray Re: *Apparently you are now explicitly alerting people when one of their recent flags has been declined.* This isn't that recent and [was implemented 3 and a half years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405). You just didn't have it until your last declined flag ([see also](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238169)).

Comment: This comment thread has pretty clearly already covered this but these are all _absolutely awful_ reasons for not handling spam as, well, spam.  Attempting to justify a bad decision just digs the hole deeper and lowers the overall reputation of the moderation team. Somebody messed up. Don't try to cover for them.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365713/4032703) for why I think that this is wrong. One of the most basic principles of Stack Overflow moderation is that we moderate content, not users, here. Applying these criteria is absolutely moderating users rather than content.

Answer (score 150):

The question is pretty clearly spam.

It advertises a product and it doesn't ask a question.

Personally, I'm a little surprised by the [actions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39286905/timeline) on this question.

1. *"9 hours ago"**, it had 3 downvotes, and 3 delete votes.
2. About an hour ago, it went through the triage queue (Probably as a result of [Sven's flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333722/how-is-this-question-not-spam/333726#comment390591_333722)), where it was [deemed "Unsalvageable"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13546283)
3. After which, *a mod* closed it as *"unclear what you're asking"*
4. This meta question was posted.
5. It was deleted by 2 users and *a mod*

In my opinion, it should've been deleted as spam, at step 3.
The *disputed* "spam" flag probably resulted from that step.

Since the user doesn't have any rep, the rep penalty associated with it wouldn't be an issue, but the note it'd leave for the mods could be of use in the future.

But then again, us users can't see all the info about a user. As has been explained in comments and TLM's answer, the flag was disputed because it *has* merit, but "spam" is a bit too severe.

<sub>*: *"9 hours ago"* is probably meant to say *"today"*. This seems to be a summary of the actions, up to this moment.</sub>

Comment: I think the line "9 hours ago" in the timeline is the summary for today (so it has a wrong date), the question was only asked 1 hour ago.

Comment: @Tunaki: Eeehm, good point. Issue with the timeline? Answer edited.

Comment: Slight correction - the flag was **disputed** not declined. There's a difference. "Declined" means "no, you were wrong", "disputed" (in this context) means "your flag has merit, but it's not spam".

Comment: @ChrisF: corrected in the answer :-)

Comment: _"This seems to be a summary of the actions, up to this moment."_ Doubt it, as there's now an another action labelled "3 hours ago", on top of the older actions with similarly appropriately-labelled time durations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Votes get summarized [with the timestamp of the beginning of the day in which they were cast, as opposed to the end](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271996/timeline-vote-summary-shows-votes-for-the-24-hours-following-the-timestamp-whic). Other actions are not similarly summarized and have reasonable timestamps.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Nope. I was reading at ~9pm, and there were lines saying "3 hours ago" and "9 hours ago", for example. I'm looking now, at 12pm, and the latest entry says "21 hours ago"; hovering over it reveals the timestamp "14:07:56Z". That may be the beginning of the day somewhere, but speaking personally I wouldn't wish to live in a country with a timezone of +1407.94 :D

Comment: .... oh, votes. Missed that caveat entirely lol. Oooook never mind

Answer (score 25):

*My 2 cents about this spam flag disputed instead of approved.*

Sure it is perfectly fine that moderators choose to not spam nuke a post and instead close and delete it, when looking at **all** the contribution that user have made to SO.

However, a "disputed flag", raise a question to flagger, "What was wrong here"?

I think since the post in itself (not considering **all** other activity of user), is a typical spam post, furthermore a *normal* user specially if <10K can't see all user activity (user could have had other 10 spam posts and we would not know).

**Conclusion:** It would have been a better user experience if flag was "Approved", let us only moderate the post as we should let moderators moderate the user.

Comment: I agree with you here. Unfortunately, when we "clear spam flags" (i.e, mark them as disputed), there is no option to "comment there" (not your problem, yes :P). Also, considering the vast number of flags that have to be handled, we find it difficult to "type the exact reason for declining" as well.

Comment: Then just check'em approved (in these cases, post in it self is spam) and we avoid to much confusion and complexity for us with simple mind. : )

Comment: @PetterFriberg Marking a spam flag as helpful makes it an audit case. Not to mention, if there's something for the user to learn from with this post, e.g. *it shouldn't be spam flagged*, marking it as helpful would be very counter-intuitive. Perhaps with smaller-sites that would work, but at SO scale, mods don't really have the time to handhold.

Comment: @hichris123, I can't see how that post would have been a bad audit, if you click "Looks ok", you probably should be banned from auditing. Furthermore, your are expecting to much from regular users who does not have all information (and have not been around in chats to know all about how mods evaluate user etc).  Note: I'm considering the post spam (hence with only post info spam flag ok) and I do not think the work for mods whether a VLQ flag or Spam flag is that much different. Conclusion in this case no education is needed.

Comment: @hichris123 that post would be way better audit than many others.

Comment: Yeah, this would be a decent audit case in this specific instance @Alexei/Petter. However, in the *general* case, posts that are borderline enough for uncertainty are probably not good audit cases.

Comment: The flag wasn't even "disputed" at first, [it was **declined**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333722/how-is-this-question-not-spam?cb=1#comment390614_333722). The status was changed to disputed later.

Answer (score -76):

I was the mod who handled the original flags on those posts. As far as I can remember I originally declined them, not disputed them as you indicated and subsequent actions on the post later changed them to disputed<sup>1</sup>.

Here's why I did that:

The thing that makes a post spam (i.e. nefarious/malevolent) and not just bad/misguided is undisclosed affiliation. Even after a fair bit of digging around I still didn't see a single bit of evidence to suggest that there's any affiliation here. In fact I'd say the evidence is more the opposite. If the OP were affiliated with CloudEra they wouldn't post awful questions like: ["In Cloudera Quickstart VM how to upgrade latest version of JDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277516/in-cloudera-quickstart-vm-how-to-upgrade-latest-version-of-jdk). I'm 95% certain that in the OP's mind sharing that newsletter was helpful and not something they stand to benefit from in any shape.

To elaborate on the affiliation point further: any given question (or crappy non-question) can be topical or not and totally independently have undisclosed affiliations:

```
                         | Topical | Off-topic |
------------------------------------------------
Undisclosed affiliation  | Case 1  | Case 2    |
------------------------------------------------
No affiliation           | Case 3  | Case 4    |
------------------------------------------------
```

For Cases 1,2 and 4 it's clear that they're wrong and spam and I'd usually cast a binding spam flag and destroy the account or mod message as appropriate. For Case 3 though it's not so clear cut: *if they're in the right ballpark and don't stand to benefit from the misstep does coming down hard achieve anything?* I don't believe it does and using the close/vote system to indicate the error does absolutely no harm and leaves the chance for learning/improvement open.

As for the declines, I use flag declines as an honest reflection of my appraisal of the situation. It's the only feedback given usually, if it's not honest there's basically no point in giving any feedback at all. I do that for any flag that takes investigation, be it "suspicious voting", "possible plagiarism" or spam. The message to take away from a simple flag decline like that is not that it's a major punishment, simply that the mod had a look and didn't see it your way. I didn't hand out review bans, or mod message for misuse of flags because that clearly isn't appropriate. Don't sweat it, unless you're getting a huge percentage of flag declines, nothing bad will happen. It's likely that some edge cases will come up differently when they're looked at with mod access from time to time.

To be clear it's such a terrible "question" that it isn't even a question. I took action besides just declining the flags: I down-voted it, cast a binding close vote and left it to roomba and the Q-ban algorithm signals that these actions give. Leaving it to roomba has one big advantage: the user experience from the perspective of the poster is much better - it maximizes the odds that they'll see the "it's unclear what you're asking" help center advice *and actually do better next time* (remember: this isn't a one hit wonder spam account) rather than just repeat the same mistake in a "hey where did that post go?" way. Early deletion can be harmful, fast deletion doesn't serve any benefit given that the Q was low enough scored to be excluded from the front page and tag subscription emails.

<sup>1</sup>Spam/Offensive flags, unlike other flags are a bit weird in that they can be retrospectively cleared because of the penalties they carry. But that action is grouped on all of those flags cast on that post.

Comment: New Ajax with **instant bleach** removes stubborn stains without scrubbing! For fast, easy removal of stubborn stains, greasy film, black pot marks... more and more women are switching to new, pure white Ajax. Nothing cleans and bleaches better than new Ajax.

Comment: Don't worry, guys. It's fine. I don't work for Ajax.

Comment: I only have one issue. Spam or not, that question is blatantly spammy and worthless, it should be removed. So putting aside the status of spam flags, at least the mod taking action should delete that question. As it stands, it needed two high-rep users to waste delete votes on it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak it will be removed automatically later and by not insta-deleting it the odds are much improved that the OP will understand why it was closed/deleted.

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that recently deleted posts are available to OP, and that mods can add comments with persistent notification even on deleted posts. If there isn't a way to instruct users without leaving garbage linger on the site, there should be.

Comment: They are available via that, but how many confused people do you reckon find it? And yes I can write a comment but what I want to write is pretty much exactly what the close reason already says - why would I want to manually do what a machine will do for me automatically?

Comment: The point is not that you should punish the offender harder, the point is that you should not decline valid spam flags. It is perfectly fine to educate the user as "punishment" in this case since there doesn't seem to be malicious intend, but the question is still spam and saying otherwise means that one should never flag spam questions, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @nwp based on what I see about the user and the product the spam flag is not accurate and "unclear what you're asking" is sufficient and accurate in every respect.

Comment: I can see perhaps disputing/declining spam flags on this if the user had a history of non-spam questions. However, this is indisputably spam -- it's an advertisement for a product.

Comment: I'm sorry but I see no reason what so ever to give a user that found something bad that needed to be removed a declined flag.  Disputed is one thing as I would have done the same thing(if I actually could) if the smoke detector in the SOCVR or Charcoal Room reported it.  As much as you want to communicate that this post with all the circumstances that this is not spam if it was a 1 rep user with no content it would have been fine to nuke.

Comment: *Don't sweat it, unless you're getting a huge percentage of flag declines, nothing bad will happen.* Doesn't really help when the user has to see that declined flag in there stats for the rest of the time they have the account.

Comment: @NathanOliver flag stats are private and there's no badge or reward or even expectation for 100% helpful. Am I missing some reason why that's a big thing?

Comment: The flagging dialog was only recently updated to state the affiliation requirement.  The core, to my mind, is still "exits solely to promote a product or service."  The recent addition about "Does not disclose the author's affiliation" only clouds this; it's not clear if it's an absolute requirement for flagging as spam, and I would not require it in this situation (otherwise, you are opening up to "spam away as long as you disclose you affiliation")!

Comment: @tripleee bear in mind though that the standard of proof needed for attribution isn't high: I routinely destroy accounts for "looks like they just signed up to post this crap" or "all their posts look promotinal". The point is that nobody is motivated to do behave like that unless they're affiliated, so if this was all they'd posted there'd be no question. Case 3 in my table is the only grey area. Look at it this way, if someone with 5 crummy iOS questions posted an email from Apple announcing xcode 8 as a "question" we wouldn't even be having this debate. Substitute cloudera and it differs?

Comment: (and fyi if you ever find LinkedIn accounts, blog posts on corporate blogs, more spam the same elsewhere, domain whois info, address or phone number cross-references, emails on SOA records or other evidence of undisclosed affiliation that's great info to get in a custom flag, because that's the smoking gun I look for in a less clear cut case)

Comment: @Flexo I know flags are private but every time the user goes to look at their flag stats they are going to see the declined.  I know 1 is not a big deal but when most people strive for 0 it hurts a little.  I can get behind a disputed flag but I think a declined flag is too harsh when it is a legitimate concern.

Comment: You **declined** the spam flag because the question did not fit your definition of spam well enough?! Whose team are you on? The community is what makes this site work (well, work…). It is a strong message to send to **decline** a spam flag for something that's so 100% front and center spam. **Are you telling us that we shouldn't bother?**

Comment: @Flexo I don't understand why this user was given special consideration at all. Looking at their profile, they **clearly** have not given **any** positive contributions to the site - nothing has been upvoted, and many have been downvoted. I'm not saying you should have nuked their account, but the user obviously is not in the same class as a 10k (or even 1k) user who "accidentally" posts something similar. Regardless of intent or affiliation, the post was spam, and should have been treated as such. Marking it as unclear was just wrong, the user won't learn anything from that.

Comment: Someone is trying to delete the mods' answers, here...

Comment: @Cerbrus Downvotes on meta indicate disagreement, nothing more. That probably means heavily downvoted answers on meta shouldn't be grayed out, but enh.

Comment: @zwol: There's a ___delete___ vote on both mods' answers.

Comment: @Cerbrus ... Why the hell does "delete" even *exist* on meta?!  Oh well. File as yet another horrifically broken thing about this site that the hivemind probably thinks is Just Fine so what even is the use of reporting it.