# Why is this question spam (encountered as triage review audit)?

Tags: discussion, triage

I failed this triage review audit already twice now:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13551014

First time, I selected "Looks OK", second time "Requires Editing". But the question is considered spam by the system, so I failed the audit. Please help me understand this: why is it spam?

To me it seems like a reasonable programming question (some unexpected behavior of a piece of code), although I have no clue what the code means, or what `puppet` is. But following the philosophy of the triage review, i.e. a **quick** check to categorize questions, I believe that shouldn't play a role. If a question looks OK on a glance, but is actually inappropriate for this site, that should not be something that triage should solve. There are other review queues and vote down/close/on-hold/flag/comment options for deeper review by more knowledgeable users.

The funny thing is that even after careful looking into the question, I still don't understand why it is spam.

So,

- How could I have recognized this question as spam?
- How could I have recognized this question as spam **quickly**?

Note the question is more specific than the possible duplicate.

Comment: That looks like a very bad audit. Apparently, what happened is that the user was destroyed, along with all its negatively scored posts, one of which was the question in question. I would guess this is why it turned into a possible audit review. [Judging from the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38870798/timeline), I count 10 people that failed the audit.

Comment: I can't follow that link. Not enough rep I guess.

Comment: Looks like the linked question asked about automated socket puppetry. That may be the reason why it was closed. Though I have to agree it shouldn't be used as an audit actually.

Comment: If shouldn't be an audit, who can take it out?

Comment: @tvo _"If shouldn't be an audit, who can take it out?"_ I believe mods can do that. So asking here was the right reaction to bring that onto their attention.

Comment: Well, "this is spam" [no longer means "post actually contains spam"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333764/), so it stands to reason that non-spam could be marked as "spam" if...something.

Comment: How does the dupe target have anything to do with the question? The dupe target asks about a system message being displayed unrelated to any actual post, this question asks about why a post with zero links or product names is considered spam.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're right, that's a bad audit. I've cleared the spam flag, which should remove it from circulation.

What happened was that a moderator cast a single hard spam flag on the post, I think in an attempt to place an IP block on someone who was spewing garbage on the site. That had the unfortunate side effect of tagging this as an audit case.

Sorry about that, but clearing the spam flag should prevent future reviewers from hitting this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: How come mods can't block IPs manually?

Comment: @dorukayhan because IP blocks aren't all they're cracked up to be - you can get a new IP pretty easily. It's more effective to allow moderators to block an *account*, which is more effort to create another of.

Comment: @dorukayhan - This is a bit more sophisticated than blocking just one IP. We're identifying the post and user to the system as a spammer / troll, and the system applies levels of intelligent blocks based on the signal it receives.