# Etiquette for referencing off-site content

Tags: discussion

As a relatively new SO user, I'm trying to learn the etiquette for a high quality SO answer. Specifically, I'd like some feedback on what's acceptable for referring people to off-site content. For example, I recently answered a question on [Caching the mean of a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918861/caching-the-mean-of-a-vector-in-r-list/47723118#47723118), referencing an extensive answer I independently published 18 months ago on my [Github site](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-breakingDownMakeVector.md). Is it preferable to summarize the offsite content on SO, or simply to refer people to the offsite content?

Comment: You should never post link-only answers. If you do, they will probably get deleted as very low quality. It's best to summarize the offsite content, and you can always post the link for reference. I've also seen cases where the offsite content is copy-pasted ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612476/4284627)), but if you do that, be sure to format the copy-pasted content as a quote and specify the source like they did in the example I linked to.

Comment: @DonaldDuck - Thanks. If I own the offsite content, do I need to post it as a quote? It seems pretentious to quote myself. I already quote others' content because it's important to give credit to the source(s).

Comment: On MSE: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94022)

Comment: You probably don't need to actually mark your own words as quotations. But it is definitely wise to mention that you posted the same material elsewhere; otherwise it might be mistaken for plagiarism of someone else's work. And if you _link_ to the other thing, it's basically required. We've apparently decided to [define "spam" around here as "referring to any thing the answerer made"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333764/) instead of "promoting a commercial activity" (of course linking to your blog can be both if you're getting ad revenue).

Comment: @JoshCaswell - in this specific situation, the article I wrote is the definitive answer to the SO question, given that I'm a Community Mentor in the online course about which the question was asked. I'm not generating ad revenue from my Github site, but can easily copypasta an excerpt to SO since it's written in markdown.

Comment: _"not generating ad revenue from my Github site"_ Yeah, I understand, and to me that would make it totally okay to link to. I'm just warning you that other people seem to think that the simple fact that it's yours would make such a post spam.

Comment: Understood, and most of the off-site references I've made in my SO posts to date are to things like term definitions on Wikipedia, versus my own content.