# Customer support vs. spam

Tags: discussion, review-queues, spam

In today's review I ran across two answers by the same user that I was unsure if it was appropriate to flag as spam. The answers seem to be useful to me. For me the two posts are edge cases. Would a flag be appropriate or would a comment have been enough?

> [image: Answer suggesting support channel]

---

> [image: Answer to question about product terms]

Comment: Related: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first one isn't an answer, it's just a pointer to another place where there might possibly be some information. Go ahead and flag that as "Not an answer".

The other one is an answer to [a non-programming question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company), so the correct action there is to flag the *question* as off-topic. The answer will go along with it when the question is deleted.

Neither of these is really spam, because they're not unsolicited advertisement for a commercial product.

Comment: That is not how [spam is defined on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Whether it's commercial or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Quite true, unfortunately, which leads us into nonsense like this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333722/how-is-this-question-not-spam

Answer (score 2):

While it's not 100% clear that they are actual spam, it IS 100% clear that they should be removed in one way or another. The first is a clear NAA. The second is likely to also be NAA, but it could also be VLQ in combination with a question that's likely OT.

So neither of these should be here in any case.